# Add item in list in specific position

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find if i can add an item in list in specific position.
Example

```
string[] tokens= new string[10];
tokens[5]="TestString";
```

when i'm trying this to list

```
 List<string> mitems = new List<string>();
 mitems.Insert(5, "TestString");
```

I'm getting error list inside a list index out of range.
Is there any relative to this for a list?

Comment: Do you mean you want to build your list by arbitrarily inserting values at random indexes? If so, no, it isn't. You can `Insert` values, but you have to choose an index between 0 (inclusive) and the current list size (exclusive), so I imagine this isn't what you want.

Comment: Has anybody read the title or the last sentece? ;)

Comment: He gave an example with an array but asked for the same method on a list...'Is there any relative to this for a list?'

Comment: Your code is totally fine, it works. But only if the list is not empty -> hence you get the index out of range. Your list is of size 0 at  the beginning, how can you insert something at index 5 if there is no index 0,1,2,3,4,5 etc? try creating an array like `string[] tokens = new string[1]` and then do `tokens[5] = "TestString`. It gives you the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Insert(index, item);` method.

Have a look at [MSDN Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Insert_System_Int32__0_) for more information.

But you will get an error when you're trying to insert an item at an index which is not existing.

You could init your list with 10 empty values like you did with your array but if you use `Insert` a new entry is created and not an old replaced like with a dictionary. That would mean you would have 11 entries after the first use of `Insert`

This example code

```
var items = new List<string>();
items.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, 10));
Console.WriteLine(items.Count);
items.Insert(5, "TestString");
Console.WriteLine(items.Count);
```

gives this output (for better understanding):

> 10
>
> 11

Comment: @Kamala OP is asking about a List, not an Array.

Comment: Thx John, you were faster :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use List<T>.Insert(int, T) method to do that, example:

```
var tokens = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    tokens.Add(string.Empty);
tokens.Insert(5, "TestString");
```

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=netframework-4.7.2)

**Edit:**
If you were just trying to replace the item in index of 5, than the [] will also do the trick as following example:

```
var tokens = new List<string>(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    tokens.Add(string.Empty);
tokens[5] = "TestString";
```

Comment: This code would throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException ;)

Comment: I'm getting error on this : list inside a list index out of range error

Comment: @Dim see my comment on your question.

Comment: Your method doesnt match in my case. Imagine that i have 10 buttons and each button it adds in a specific position it's Text. So if will use your example it will delete my already inserted values.

Comment: @Dim perhaps you would be better off describing your actual use case in your question so that we can advise you on the correct course of action to take?

Comment: I just put something in it, so it can insert in index 5. If you already have something in it, than you can just insert. Best check before insert.

Comment: Or maybe you want to replace the item in that location?

Comment: Ok you have right! Your answer actually work fine. It is my case how to handle it, and match it inside my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void Myfunc()
    {
        List<string> l = new List<string>();
        string opt = "y";
        while (opt == "y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add in a specific position? (y/n)");
            string pos = Console.ReadLine();
            if (pos == "y")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Which index you want to add?");
                int index = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Add items in {0}", index);
                l.Insert(index, Console.ReadLine());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter to add in a list");
                l.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to continue? (y/n)");
                opt = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to print the list? (y/n)");
            string print = Console.ReadLine();
            if (print == "y")
            {
                foreach (var item in l)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }

        }
```

I wrote this function for you.
Add this function to a console app for better understanding how list works for insert and append

EDIT 1:

I just saw your edit, another way of initializing a list with default values and then insert something in a certain position would be by initializing the list like this :-

```
List<string> l = Enumerable.Repeat("something blank", 10).ToList();
```

And then add to an index of your choice

Comment: Won't work any better. Try adding index 5 on your first iteration.

Comment: I just edited the answer, try out and let me know. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following adds default values of string at every index from 0-9

```
string[] tokens= new string[10];
```

But **list is created on heap nothing instantiated**. No default assigned values.

```
List<string> mitems = new List<string>();
```

If you try following it will fail as there are no values at 0-5

```
mitems.Insert(5, "TestString");
```

If you do following it will **work**

```
mitems.Insert(0, "TestString");
```